# Protractor: how to click all delete buttons in a page object

Tags: protractor

I have a table with 3 rows of data and 3 delete buttons. I want to delete all rows of data and so am trying to write a method in my page object to do so... this should be a snap but I can't get it to work. I'm trying it like this:

```
this.rows = element.all(by.repeater('row in rows'));

this.deleteAllFriends = function() {
    this.rows.each(function(row) {
        row.$('i.icon-trash').click();
    })
};
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error: Index out of bound. Trying to access index:2, but locator: by.repeater("row in rows") only has 1 elements
```

So obviously, the index protractor expects next is no longer there, because it's been deleted. **How can I work around this?**

This also does not work and throws the same error:

```
this.deleteButtons = $$('i.icon-trash');

this.deleteAllFriends = function() {
    this.deleteButtons.each(function(button) {
        button.click();
    });
};
```

This also doesn't work...

```
this.deleteAllFriends = function() {
    while(this.deleteButton.isDisplayed()) {
        this.deleteButton.click();
    }
};
```

Comment: In most cases, when you are deleting "all" of something that is in an array/list, you want to delete backwards. This way the index isn't interrupted/changed by the first delete. This is a GENERAL comment. I don't know protractor, there may be an easier/cleaner way to do it in this case -- which is why I'm posting a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With today's [version >= 1.3.0 of Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases/tag/1.3.0) you are now be able to [do this at once](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/466b3831569dc28c5fc2be31fbdf96574e57c3f0)

```
$$('i.icon-trash').click();
```

> feat(protractor): allow advanced features for ElementArrayFinder

Comment: I upgraded to 1.3.0 but this does not work for me. Calling directly from my spec and/or a page object, I get:

`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'click'`

Comment: Are you sure you upgraded? Works for my test suite and I've just added another [test case in Protractor source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1367/files) to make sure it works.

Comment: That's weird, I guess if you can write a small test case to reproduce it [you can report](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/new) a 1.3.0 Protractor bug since is not working as expected.

Comment: Leo, I'm using WebStorm with a Node.js runner that requires (afaik) you to specify the `cli.js` (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js). Could this be my problem? Ie. am I pointing to an "old one"? I don't see another... just wondering.

Comment: Yeah, I think is more likely that you're using an older Protractor than this feature not correctly working in 1.3.0. Can't help you with that config though.

Comment: Yeah, it's something with WebStorm/Node, as running it from the command line DOES work with the new code...

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out...

```
this.deleteButtons = $$('i.icon-trash'); // locator

this.deleteAllFriends = function() {
    var buttons = this.deleteButtons;

    buttons.count().then(function(count) {
        while(count > 0) {
            buttons.first().click();
            count--;
        }
    })
};
```